# LORWAN PHYheader size while transmitting?

Tags: lora, lorawan

I have been trying to figure out what the total bytes is when im transmitting a payload from my end-node to the Gateway. My payload is 25 bytes and as I understood the minimum PHYheader is 13 bytes. But how can I see how many bytes my end-device is sending?

The reason why I want to know this is because I want to calculate how long time it takes to send 25 bytes payload with different spreading factors (7-12). If I calculate this with 25 bytes it will not give me the correct result. I need some PHYheader size e.g. 13 bytes + 25 bytes = 38 bytes total or something like that. These calculations I want to compare with my measurements I made with an oscilloscope. I was sending a payload of 25 bytes with different spreading factors (7-12) and measured the time it took.

Im using the following example code on my End-node to connect to the Gateway:

Code: https://github.com/ARMmbed/mbed-os-example-lorawan

End-node: [Development board B-L072Z-LRWAN1](https://www.st.com/en/evaluation-tools/b-l072z-lrwan1.html#quickview-scroll)

Gateway: Connected to OTA/ABP [Kerlink LoRa IoT Station](https://www.thethingsnetwork.org/docs/gateways/kerlink/)

I found this link but I get really confused when im reading this. https://lora-alliance.org/resource-hub/lorawantm-specification-v11

The total bytes send is not specific for a end-device, but more specific for the lorawan communication as I understood it. Can anyone help me on how I find out the total number of bytes i'm transmitting when sending a payload of 25 bytes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please follow my thoughts below:

> But how can I see how many bytes my end-device is sending?

From my experience, I modified the driver provided by the end-node vendor to check the frame size sent by the end-node (e.g., RN2483).

> Can anyone help me on how I find out the total number of bytes I'm transmitting when sending a payload of 25 bytes?

I notice that the end-node you are using is embedded with SX1276. SX1276 is made by Semtech. There is an equation for on-air time calculation in [Semtech Designer’s Guide](https://www.semtech.com/uploads/documents/LoraDesignGuide_STD.pdf). And you could find a [LoRa airtime calculator form](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1voGAtQAjC1qBmaVuP1ApNKs1ekgUjavHuVQIXyYSvNc/edit?usp=sharing) or a [tool](https://github.com/tanupoo/lorawan_toa) written in Python.